# Using read() system call

Tags: c, system-calls

For an assignment in class we were tasked with using the `read()` function to read a file containing numbers.  While I was able to read the numbers into a buffer I have been unable to move them from the buffer into a char *array so that they can be easily accessed and sorted.  Any advice is appreciated.

```
int readNumbers(int hexI, int MAX_FILENAME_LEN, int **array, char* fname) {
    int numberRead = 0, cap = 2;
    *array = (int *)malloc(cap*sizeof(int));
    int n;
    int filedesc = open(fname, O_RDONLY, 0);
    if(filedesc < 0){
        printf("%s: %s\n", "COULD NOT OPEN", fname);
        return -1;
    }
    char * buff = malloc(512);
    buff[511] = '\0';
   while(n = read(filedesc, buff+totaln, 512 - totaln) > 0) //Appears to loop only once
            totaln += n;
    int len = strlen(buff);
    for (int a = 0; a < len; a++) {  //Dynamically allocates array according to input size
        if ((&buff[a] != " ") && (&buff[a] != '\n'))
            numberRead++;
        if (numberRead >= cap){
            cap = cap*2;
            *array = (int*)realloc(*array, cap*sizeof(int));
        }
    }
    int k = 0;
    while((int *)&buff[k]){  //attempts to assign contents of buff to array
        array[k] = (int *)&buff[k];
        k++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you writing the read data into a char *buff[512] instead of a single char * buff = malloc(MAX_FILENAME_LEN)?

Comment: buff is holding the contents of the file, not the filename.  However,  I did change char *buff[512] to char * buff = malloc(512). 512 was recommended by the professor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your use of `read()` is wrong.  There are at least two serious errors:

1. You ignore the return value, except to test for end-of-file.
2. You seem to assume that `read()` will append a nul byte after the data it reads.  Perhaps even that it will pad out the buffer with nul bytes.

If you want to read more data into the same buffer after `read()` returns, without overwriting what you already read, then you must pass a pointer to the first *available* position in the buffer.  If you want to know how many bytes were read in total, then you need to add the return values.  The usual paradigm is something like this:

```
/*
 * Read as many bytes as possible, up to buf_size bytes, from file descriptor fd
 * into buffer buf.  Return the number of bytes read, or an error code on
 * failure.
 */
int read_full(int fd, char buf[], int buf_size) {
    int total_read = 0;
    int n_read;

    while ((n_read = read(fd, buf + total_read, buf_size - total_read)) > 0) {
        total_read += n_read;
    }

    return ((n_read < 0) ? n_read : total_read);        
}
```

Having done something along those lines and not received an error, you can be assured that `read()` has not modified any element of the buffer beyond `buf[total_read - 1]`.  It certainly has not filled the rest of the buffer with zeroes.

Note that it is not always necessary or desirable to read until the buffer is full; the example function does that for demonstration purposes, since it appears to be what you wanted.

Having done that, be aware that you are trying to extract numbers as if they were recorded in binary form in the file.  That may indeed be the case, but if you're reading a *text* file containing *formatted* numbers then you need to extract the numbers differently.  If that's what you're after then add a string terminator after the last byte read and use `sscanf()` to extract the numbers.

Comment: Thanks, I kinda understand what you're doing but I still am missing the core concept.  I really don't see how storing the bytes read is going to help.  numbersRead is meant to store the number of ints in the file not the number of bytes read by read().  Also I'm still not seeing how to make the information read into the buffer useful. While printf("%s\n", buff) displays the entire file I don't see a way to split the file up into an int array of ints (which is my ultimate goal here).  Also, the .txt file it is reading was made with notepad++ and has no character formatting.

Comment: In a `read()` loop you need to track the the total number of bytes read up to that point so as to read the *next* bytes into the correct part of the buffer, instead of overwriting what you already read.  At the end, you need the total number read to know how much of the buffer is occupied by valid data.  The example code shows how to do that properly.  As for extracting numbers from the data you have read, see the last paragraph of my answer.